# "Come + X" construct

Tags: syntactic-analysis, clauses

I've come across the "come + X" construct in a passage of a New York Times article. Here it is (emphasis added):

> Politicians like to keep the fiscal levers in their hands **come
>   election time**

What kind of clause does it introduce? Plus, how common is it? Is it typically American? Formal or informal? Are there any other instances where it is used, besides "come election time," which seems to me a set phrase? Lastly, which mood is that "come"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an example of the formulaic subjunctive, found also in fixed expressions such as ‘Suffice it to say’ and ‘Be it noted’. Its use is not confined to the United States. It’s found in British speech as, for example, ‘They’ll have been away two weeks come Sunday.’

Comment: Can ‘They’ll have been away two weeks come Sunday’ be rephrased as ‘Sunday will mark the second week since they have left’? (I realize that's an awkward rephrasing, but I just wanted to make sure I grasped the meaning.)

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning.

Comment: So, in the above-mentioned sentence taken from the NYT, "come election time" means "in case of elections," doesn't it?

Comment: @Giorgiomastrò: No, it means 'when election time comes'.

Comment: _When_ for a normally recurring event, _if_ for a potential one. There are also idioms like "_came the dawn_", a comment on someone's discovering something they should already have figured out, and "_come the Revolution_", meaning if/when the Revolution ever happens, etc. Essentially _come_ has become a temporal preposition with this specialized sense.

Comment: Can "come to think of it" (e.g. "Come to think of it, I've run out of money too") be classed as another example of formulaic subjunctive?

Comment: @Giorgiomastrò: Not sure. It may be an ellipsed form of 'If I come to think of it'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see its usage as especially formal but it isn't in common informal usage - I hear phrases such as "come daybreak" or "come end of play" occasionally in the UK.